# Communication between local agent and remote agent deployed over cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, agents-jade

We have deployed a ping agent which is deployed over Amazon EC2 instance in the cloud and we want to communicate to it by means of a local agent but i am getting an error message when i send an ACL message to the cloud agent by local agent as below:

((action 
     (agent-identifier 
       :name da1@10.99.2.165:1099/JADE
       :addresses (sequence  http ://Shahrukh:7778/acc)) (ACLMessage)) 
   (MTS-error 
     (agent-identifier 
       :name ping@platform1:1098/JADE
       :addresses 
         (sequence http://ip.120-10-228-29-245.ec2.internal:7778/acc)) 
     (internal-error "Foreign agent unreachable: No valid address contained within the AID ping@platform1:1098/JADE")))

Does any one know why is it so??

Comment: Try using external IPs and DNSs instead of the internal IPs (`10.99.2.165`) and DNSs (`http://ip.120-10-228-29-245.ec2.internal`)

Answer (score 0):

Open ports 7778 and 1099 on the security group that your EC2 instance is using.

[image: Security Group]

Comment: I have done as you said but it is giving same error now. @Rico